# Mapping a store to a proxy

Tags: javascript, extjs, model, proxy, store

So I'm trying to configure an ajax proxy in extjs that reads a 'users.json' file. I'm attempting to map my store to the users.json file. Here's my store:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.User',
    fields: ['name', 'email']
}
```

Here's my users.json file:

```
{
    success: true,
    users: [
        {name: 'Ed Hayes',              email: 'aaa'},
        {name: 'Tommy Gunz', email: 'tommy@sencha.com'},
        {name: 'Clay Banks',    email: 'clay@BoA.com'},
        {name: 'Billy Joe', email: 'billyJgeemail.com'},
        {name: 'James Bond', email: 'goldenGun@HQ.com'}
    ]
}
```

And lastly, my model:

```
Ext.define('AM.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name', 'email'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'data/users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    }
});

// Uses the User Model's Proxy
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'AM.model.User'
});
```

Right now it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to do this? (Is this something I should even be doing?)

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  What code are you using to try to access the data, and what symptoms occur?

Comment: Did any of the answers below work for you?  If not, can you post your solution and mark it as the answer?  Other wise I am going to delete my answer.

Comment: I believe this would work, but there are some client/server issues here on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the proxy on the store, not the model in your case.  Also, I'm not sure if the way you set up the models is a working way of doing it or not, here's how I would set up the model and store in question:

```
Ext.define("AM.store.User", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name:"name",  type:"string"},
        {name:"email", type:"string"}
    ]
});

// Uses the User Model's Proxy
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'AM.store.User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'data/users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Comment: Also, I think that in practicality you need to save the store off to a variable for it to be useful.  Not sure if you left that out of your example or not.

Comment: A store will inherit its model's proxy, so it doesn't matter. The default type of a field is string, so it doesn't matter if you leave that out. You don't need to save it to a variable, you could put it directly in a grid.

Answer (score 0):

1. Either use the `model` property in your `store`, or use the `fields` property. Don't use both.
2. You don't need the `success` property in the json (you only need that with certain extjs form operations)
3. Why are you creating a default store with a model, when you've already declared your own type of store?
4. You can put the `proxy` in the `store` or `model`. The `store` will inherit its `model`'s `proxy` if it doesn't have one.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the proxy on the store
You can map your store by this process.
Here code.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model     : 'AM.store.User',
    idProperty: 'id',
    autoLoad  : false,
    autoSync  : true,

    remoteSort: true,
    pageSize  : 10,
    proxy: {
        type    : 'ajax',
        noCache : false,
        limitParam: 'limit',
        startParam: 'start',
        url : 'data/users.json',
        actionMethods: {
            create  : 'POST',
            read    : 'GET',
            update  : 'PUT',
            destroy : 'DELETE'            
        },
        reader: {
            type            : 'json',
            root            : 'data',
            totalProperty   : 'total',
            successProperty : 'success',
            messageProperty : 'message',
            implicitIncludes: true
        },
        simpleSortMode  : true
    },
    sorters: [{
        property: 'id', 
        direction: 'asc'
    }]
});
```